# Add free space available on disk to partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to add free 8gb available that I left when I was installing Ubuntu. I downloaded GParted iso and used Unetbootin to create USB. When I boot from USB, I can't resize `dev/sda5` to add free 8gb available, it's colored gray and I can't move it to the right, to add more space. How do I do that, what am I missing?

UPD: I screened it from my Ubuntu because I can't screen it from the USB, but I'm booting from USB, when I'm trying to resize.
[image]

UPD:  <strike>Addition to PonJar's answer. I found similar answer, in short: it's the same what he said, but it leaves unnecessary 1 mb free space between partitions, in order to get rid of them you need to apply every change, as I understood, before doing the next, but it also somehow will take 1mb from your previous partition, it wasn't critical (I think so, hopefully) when moving from `dev/sda6` to `dev/sda5` since I have a lot of unused space in `dev/sda6`, but it might be critical when I was moving from `dev/sda7` to `dev/sda6`, since it's only 95 mb, I avoided that by leaving 1 mb when moving free space and it didn't change from 95 to 94 as it was before.</strike>  Read the PonJar's comments about it.

Comment: It's mounted, you need to do it via live usb.

Comment: @Liso, I did it from USB, read the post, I can't screenshot from USB, that's why I screened it from my Ubuntu

Comment: Then what prevent you from unmount it ? From the image I see that `/dev/sda4` is swap partition.

Comment: @Liso, I edited the post, I wanted to add the size to dev/sda5, not sda4, and as I said this screen is from Ubuntu gparted, not from the USB Gparted

Comment: GParted will ensure that your partitions are correctly aligned. That can mean that sometimes you get the 1MB gaps that you report. If it didn’t do this you would get performance issues

Comment: @PonJar, is it bad that I got rid of them then, as I described in the post?

Comment: *is it bad that I got rid of them* Time and usage will tell. They're there for a reason. It isn't a bug or quirk.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, any ways I can fix this now? Should I worry about it?

Comment: You can check your partition alignment with the parted tool. Type “sudo parted /dev/sda” in a terminal. Then at the parted prompt type “print”. That will give you a list of your partitions and a number to use for each. Then type “align-check optimal”. You will then be prompted for a partition number. Enter that and it will tell you if that partition is aligned. Type q to exit parted

Comment: @PonJar, thanks, if they're all aligned, it's good, right?

Comment: Yes, aligned is good. If they are not aligned it’s not the end of the world, it will work. Only consider doing something about it if the performance seems slow. Any improvement that is possible may not be noticeable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move the space first so that it’s next to sda5. To do that move sda7 fully to the right into the unallocated space. The space will then be between sda7 and sda 6. Then move sda6 in the same way. Then you can expand sda5.

Comment: In short terms, that's correct answer, but I added some details to this answer in the post.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can't add your free 8gb to dev/sda5, because both are not neighbour drives. You can join them if they are neighbour drives. Just create a new partition for free 8gb and link it to dev/sda5.